# Целые три минуты и целых три часа

Tags: числительные

Он пришел позже на целые три минуты. Я ждал тебя целых три часа. Выбор ЦЕЛЫЕ/ЦЕЛЫХ зависит от рода существительного, или можно пользоваться любой формой?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1.Это правило носит ПОЛУЭМПИРИЧЕСКИЙ характер. Примерно таким же  является правило согласования сказуемого с однородными подлежащими, когда  приходится учитывать различные факторы, в том числе согласование сказуемого может  с БЛИЖАЙШИМ подлежащим – так язык стремится избежать явного противоречия между двумя СОСЕДНИМИ словами.

2.Такая же ситуация и здесь, непосредственно она касается числительных ДВА, ТРИ, ЧЕТЫРЕ, которые сочетаются с сущ. в ед. числе.   Если существительное имеет СОВПАДАЮЩИЕ ФОРМЫ  ед. и мн. числа вида «НЕТ МЕДАЛИ – ТРИ  МЕДАЛИ», то  следует сказать «три ЗОЛОТЫЕ медали». Так мы можем избежать неприятного на слух сочетания  «золотых медали»

3.Такое явление  встречается  среди существительных ЖЕНСКОГО РОДА обоих склонений, но практически невозможно для  сущ. мужского рода – там совпадающие формы И.п.  мн.числа и Р.п. ед. числа ОТЛИЧАЮТСЯ хотя бы ударением: дом – нет дОма – домА .

4.В итоге мы получаем  ОСНОВНОЕ ПРАВИЛО согласования прилагательного и существительного в Р.п.:  три ВЫСОКИХ  дерева,  три БОЛЬШИХ дома,  три  ПОСЛЕДНИХ строфы. И ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ, которое мы уже объяснили: три ВЫСОКИЕ сосны. Думаю, что используются эти формы чисто ИНТУИТИВНО – кто  и кому  будет объяснять такие тонкости! Но понаблюдать за речью интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от рода.Я ждал тебя целых три часа. Муж.род - род.п.

Перед существительными мужского и среднего рода прилагательное всегда стоит в родительном падеже множественного числа: «два высоких холма». Эта же форма прилагательного употребляется перед существительным женского рода в случае, если именительный падеж множественного числа у этого существительного («гóры») отличается (хотя бы лишь по ударению) от родительного падежа единственного числа («гор́ы»). Поэтому следует говорить: «две высоких горы». Если же указанные формы у существительного женского рода в точности совпадают («есть многие вершины» — «нет ни единой вершины»), то прилагательное обычно стоит в именительном падеже множественного числа: «две высокие вершины».

Оговорка «обычно» тут отнюдь не случайна: в некоторых трудно формализуемых ситуациях за прилагательным сохраняется форма родительного падежа множественного числа. Сравните, к примеру:
Были разыграны три бронзовые медали.
Было разыграно три бронзовых медали.

Comment: Я думаю, Р.п. с В.п. не следует смешивать. Хотя путаница в СРЯ давно присутствует)  
Ф. М. Достоевский. Двойник (1846)  
Фраза, во-первых, очень хорошо шла к настоящему его положению, а во-вторых, чего же не придет в голову человеку, выжидающему счастливой развязки обстоятельств своих почти **битые три часа** в сенях, в темноте и на холоде?

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ: я из него извлекла важную информацию по поводу совпадающих форм.  Дело в том, что в учебниках исключение связывается с ЖЕНСКИМ РОДОМ, но, оказывается,  оно касается только ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫХ существительных женского рода.

Comment: Дерзкий grantum, всё дело в том, как даются  сведения  по конкретному написанию.  В жесткой форме, с перечислением всех «если» они, безусловно,  раздражают: выучить всё это весьма затруднительно. Но если ситуация объясняется, то всё выглядит иначе.  Я попробую привести вариант такого объяснение в дополнении к вопросу.

Comment: Дерзкий grantum, это не путаница,это творчество, непризнание формальностей. Ф.Достоевский этой формой хотел сказать, что эти три часа ему были интересны каждый в отдельности, в темноте и холоде они тянулись, каждый час был битым.Вот в моём примере разобрались? Были разыграны три бронзовые медали. Смысл в том, что разыгрывалась каждая медаль в отдельности, за каждую шла борьба. Было разыграно три бронзовых медали.-констатация факта, что всего разыграно в сумме три. Безличная форма стирает интерес к каждой медали, интересует только количество.

Comment: Три медали - слитное словосочетание, но семантика его может быть разной, а значит, и согласование разное.

Comment: Три бр-е медали  и три бр-ых медали - равнозначные варианты и оба небезупречны с грамматической точки зрения. Но они прижились и используются на практике, все нормально. Никакой семантической разницы (*по отдельности* или *всего*) в них не улавливается, увы. НЕ проглядывается даже под микроскопом. Ср. : пять бронзовых медалей (Р.п., мн.ч.). Все правильно согласовано и вариант этот **единственный**, хоть врозь медали считай, хоть всем скопом.

Comment: Для решения вопроса можно обратиться к статистике. Если в поисковике набрать "три золотых медали", то он выдаст 3-4 таких варианта и перейдет к "три золотые медали". Если наоборот, то перехода нет. Что касается формы "разыграно три бронзовых медали", то здесь, скорее, сказывается влияние сказуемого в ед. числе, а не наличие какого-то особого смысла.

Comment: Попробовала. Поисковик выдает вперемешку, пролистала несколько страниц, употребление примерно одинаковое.

Answer (score 1):

Никто не сделает ошибки в следующих случаях:
Три тетради, четыре девочки ( существительные женского рода ставятся в им. пад) 
Тетради какие? - Общие. Значит говорим:  три общие толстые тетради ( согласование в падеже, в числе ) 
Три парня, сто два карандаша  ( сущ. муж. рода ставятся в род. падеже) 
 Три высоких парня
 В комнату вошли три высоких парня и две стройные девушки 
Просто надо применять правило, которое в данном случае довольно простое: числительные 2-3- 4 и все числительные, заканчивающие на эти числа, т.е. на два. три четыре, как то: 23, 54, 102 ( но не тринадцать, в котором есть лишь цифра 3, но нет слова три),
идя  в паре с существительными жен. рода  требуют именительного падежа, 
идя в паре с существительными муж. рода требуют родительного падежа. 
Значит, правильно писать: я ждал тебя целых три часа, но три целые минуты

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то к правилу "Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре" Розенталь делает дополнение, касающееся прилагательных *целый, полный, добрый*: "Однако прилагательные *целый, полный, добрый* и некоторые другие обычно употребляются в этом случае в форме родительного падежа: *целых два месяца, целых две недели, полных два ведра, добрых двое суток, лишних три часа*. Например: ...*Принужден был иногда целых три часа стоять, прижавшись к стене* (Пушкин); *Да и бил он меня каких-нибудь месяца два* (Достоевский)". Т**ак что *целых три минуты* и *целых три часа*.** Или есть и другие авторитетные источники?

Кроме перечисленных нюансов (ударения и формы сказуемого) Розенталь выделяет еще один: "При наличии перед всем оборотом предлога возможны варианты; ср.: *на две равные части* – *по две столовых ложки*".