# Каждые два часа и целых два часа

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, с помощью какого правила объяснить разницу,  почему не говорим "каждых два часа"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29165/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: В окне Поиска по сайту — паутина. Надо смахнуть

Comment: По ссылке немного другая тема: там разный род и одинаковые определения, а здесь мужской род и разные определения.

Answer (score 2):

Просто потому, что "каждых два часа" - неправильно.

Вы не совсем правильно вопрос ставите. Во-первых, на вопрос, начинающийся с  "почему", предполагается ответ, раскрывающую некую причинно-следственную связь, а её в грамматике крайне редко удается найти. Есть просто некий факт, с которым надо считаться.
Во-вторых, на самом деле исключением в подобных конструкциях является не именительный падеж ("каждые два") а именно родительный ("целых два"). Он используется только для некоторых определений и только в некоторых случаях. Вот конкретно про наш случай *у Розенталя*:

> §193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два,
>   три, четыре
>
> .....
>   4.      Если определение стоит перед счетным оборотом, то оно ставится в форме именительного падежа независимо от рода имени
>   существительного: каждые два часа, последние два предложения, лучшие
>   две песни. Например: Первые три года она только урывками наезжала в
>   Заболотье (Салтыков-Щедрин); Последние два слова были написаны крупным
>   и размашистым, решительным почерком (Тургенев); Остальные три
>   лошади... шли сзади (Шолохов).
>
> ***Однако прилагательные целый, полный, добрый и некоторые другие обычно
>   употребляются в этом случае в форме родительного падежа: целых два
>   месяца, целых две недели, полных два ведра, добрых двое суток, лишних
>   три часа. Например: ...Принужден был иногда целых три часа стоять,
>   прижавшись к стене (Пушкин); Да и бил он меня каких-нибудь месяца два
>   (Достоевский).***
>
> В сочетаниях с пол- и полтора (полторы) возможны обе формы
>   согласования: добрых полчаса – добрые полчаса (см. также §168, п. 2),
>   целых полторы недели – целые полторы недели.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

(курсив мой. -М.)

В списке слов, допускающих в этой конструкции родительный падеж, слова "каждый" нет. Отсюда следует, что форма "каждых два часа" ненормативна.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на  вопрос надо искать у Розенталя:

**§193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре** http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

4. Если определение стоит перед счетным оборотом, **то оно ставится в форме именительного падежа независимо от рода имени существительного**: **каждые два часа,** последние два предложения, лучшие две песни.

Однако прилагательные целый, полный, добрый и некоторые другие **обычно употребляются в этом случае в форме родительного падежа:** **целых два месяца**, целых две недели, полных два ведра, добрых двое суток, лишних три часа. Например: ...Принужден был иногда целых три часа стоять, прижавшись к стене (Пушкин);

Это правило, но ведь  заданный вопрос содержал ключевое слово "почему": **ПОЧЕМУ мы не говорим "каждых два часа", но говорим "целых два часа"?**  Потому что есть исключения? Так это Розенталь составил список исключений, у него надо было спрашивать? Это он мог бы сказать (но не сказал), почему туда попали именно эти слова, чем они особенные.  Но, может быть, и сейчас кто-нибудь это знает и даст ответ?

А ответ будет такой: не надо много рассуждать, не надо задавать эти неправильные вопросы "почему?".  Берите список, сверяйте слова, учите наизусть от сих до сих.

**Но ведь мы живем  в XXI веке, нам не подходит такая старорежимная  философия и  педагогика.** Мы должны воспитывать думающее, творческое поколение, иначе мы безнадежно отстанем от культуры и цивилизации.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Целых два часа и целые два часа:** употребляются обе формы, но с разной частотностью:

14 примеров: **Целые два часа** чувствовал он себя почти счастливым... [Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы (1880)]

69 примеров: Представляешь, пришлось ждать профессора Введенского **целых два часа!** [Александр Морозов. Прежние слова (1985-2001) // «Знамя», 2002]

1 пример: Я думал, я выиграл двенадцать минут, а теперь я теряю почти **два целых часа** (Набоков. (1998)]

2) **Каждые два часа и каждых два часа:** практически используется только первая форма.

99 примеров: Через **каждые два часа** мы сменяли друг друга у локатора. [Марк Сергеев. (1971)]

1 пример: В одни ворота через **каждых два часа** запускают немного попасшихся кобылиц... [В. Орлов. 1990]

**Пояснение**

Счетный  оборот является **единым  членом  предложения**, например: прошло два часа, прошли два часа. При подлежащем, выраженном оборотом,  сказуемое может иметь форму ед. или мн. числа, причем в ед. числе счетному обороту приписывается значение среднего рода.

В сочетании ***каждые два часа***  счетный оборот имеет  форму мн. числа  И.п., определение относится ко всему обороту и согласуется с ним.

А вот сочетание **целые два часа** может восприниматься как инверсия: два целых часа, поэтому в речи встречаются варианты.

**И общий вывод:** если определение относится **ко всему счетному обороту**, то используется форма И.п. Если же возможна **инверсия**, то есть перенос определения внутрь оборота, то применяется форма Р.п. Таких слов немного, поэтому их относят **к исключениям.**

Comment: Любопытно, что "биты**х** два часа" встречается практически только в одной форме.

Comment: Заметьте, что сочетание "**целые** два часа" в 13 из 14 раз встречается  в текстах 19-го века.

Comment: Да, значит, устарела форма, "целых два часа" кажется привычнее на слух.

Comment: Битых два часа - два битых часа. Кажется,  фразеологизм "битый час"  относят к 15 веку, когда впервые были созданы часы с боем.