# Как правильно записать эти словосочетания?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, согласование

Тема взята с другого ресурса. Даны **словосочетания**:

*Целых два месяца.*

*Последние два предложения.*

*Сыграно три новых роли.*

*Четыре остальных партии.*

*Большая часть отзывов были положительными.*

**Вопросы такие:** (1) Всё ли правильно? (2) Предложения 1 и 2 решаются по одному правилу, а ответы разные. Почему? (3) Предложение 5 имеет варианты решений, а какой выберете вы?

Спасибо.

Comment: *Можно ли очень быстро (по слуху) выбрать правильный ответ с очень коротким обоснованием* — выбор по слуху означает, что нет обоснования. Взаимоисключающие вещи.

Comment: *Четыре остальных* — это неверно.

Comment: У меня есть обоснования, но я все выбрала сначала по слуху.  Немного затруднили  решения с вариантами (оба верные, но одно из них лучше.

Comment: Ну у меня тоже по слуху, в таких случаях не запариваюсь с обоснованиями.

Comment: Вот и дайте ответ для всех сочетаний, а рядом – как вы для себя сделали выбор. Два-три предложения,  рlease. Кстати, цитирую вас: "Как человек на слух поймёт, какой вариант? Да никак! "

Comment: Да всё так, как у вас. Просто по слуху.

Comment: Стоп, там на слух не будет отличаться, а здесь огромное отличие — другое окончание. То к этому отношения не имеет.

Comment: Много слов, мало дела.  Вот экзамен, вот тест.  Найдите неправильные сочетания за короткое время. По слуху, по окончаниям, по чему угодно...

Comment: Уже нашёл, одно. Ещё есть? Такой вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473929

Comment: Кочующий вопрос... Я его изменила: не найти ошибки, а предложить ваш вариант записи. Вы нашли самую очевидную ошибку,  а еще три вопроса имеют варианты решения.  Интересно сравнить 1 и 2. Там правило одно, а решения разные. Почему? Вариант 5 неоднозначен.

Comment: Грамота вон опрос делает, как улучшить их ресурс: https://forms.yandex.ru/cloud/64a2e5dc5d2a06959996fa6b/ Напишите им, чтобы правила доработали, на все вопросы отвечали и т.п. Думаю, вы много чего можете посоветовать.

Comment: Меня тоже это заинтересовало. Несколько минут назад встретил на Грамоте объяснение: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289325 Если бы вы не спросили, не сказал бы об этом. Так что обо всём надо спрашивать. "Положительная часть отзывов" — такое себе.

Comment: Вы можете соврать. Проверить не смогут. Ну и это идёт просто в статистику, то есть просто количество, как на выборах (только уже без фальсификаций). Возраст нужно, чтобы понимать, какая целевая аудитория. Образование тоже можно понять, тоже про аудиторию. А вот зачем доход — не понимаю. Узнать, интересуются ли богачи/бедные грамотностью?

Comment: А реально. Если много богатых, то они смогут собирать на что-то, или даже вторую зарплату сделать.

Comment: Мошенники напрямую спрашивают данные карты и коды. А остальное им не поможет. А я на них обиделся за то, что не ответили на моё предложение про улучшение правил за счёт системы тикетов.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, надо знать **[правило Розенталя](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)**

**§193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре**

1. При существительных **мужского и среднего рода**, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме **родительного падежа множественного числа:** два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола.
2. При существительных **женского рода** в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится в форме **именительного падежа** (или совпадающего с ним винительного при неодушевленных существительных) множественного числа. Например: две большие комнаты, четыре фарфоровые чашки;
3. Если формы именительного падежа множественного числа существительных **женского** рода **отличаются по ударению** от формы родительного падежа единственного числа (ср.: го́ры – горы́, слёзы – слезы́), то определение в рассматриваемой конструкции обычно ставится в родительном падеже множественного числа: две высоких горы, две крупных слезы.

**В ЧЕМ СМЫСЛ ПРАВИЛА РОЗЕНТАЛЯ**

1. Нужно вспомнить, как образуется количественный оборот: *два дома, пять домов, три окна, четыре чашки, пять чашек.* В начальной форме оборота существительное стоит в форме **Р.п. мн. числа или Р.п. ед. числа** для чисел *два, три, четыре*.

Если сущ. имеет **определение**, то оно тоже используется в форме **Р.п.**, и это воспринимается нормально: *три больших окна, пять высотных домов, две высоких горы.*

2. **Поправка на благозвучие** делается только **для сущ. ж.рода,** причем здесь возможны варианты:

(1) Используется форма определения в И.п. при совпадении формы И.п. мн.числа и Р.п. ед.числа (чАшки и нет чАшки): три **большИЕ чашки** звучит лучше, чем три **большИХ чашки**.

(2) Если такого совпадения нет (гОры, нет горЫ), то для определения используется обычная форма Р.п. мн.ч., как и для сущ. м. и ср.рода: три высокИХ горы.

3. Но даже не зная этого правила, носители языка ориентируются по слуху, по сочетаемости слов. Вот здесь и может пригодиться **хорошее чувство языка.**)

В то же время Розенталь в своем правиле **четко** объяснил эту тему, в то время как наши **объяснения "на пальцах"** часто понятны только самим объясняющим.

[Обсуждение темы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29165/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%98%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE,%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%3A%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B)

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

**Мужской и средний род**

***Целых два месяца**. Два целых месяца.* **Корректно**.

*Последние два предложения. Два последние предложения. **Некорректно**. Надо: **Два последних предложения***.

**Женский род**

***Сыграно три новых роли***. **Корректно**. Сравнить: роли (И.п. мн.ч.) – нет роли (Р.п. ед.ч.), формы совпадают, см. п. 2(1). Но в данном случае делается **поправка на синтаксис** для согласования, сравнить: сыгранЫ три новЫЕ роли / сыгранО три новЫХ роли.

Четыре остальных партии.  **Некорректно.** Надо: ***Четыре остальные партии**.* Сравнить: партии (И.п. мн.ч.) – нет партии (Р.п. ед.ч.), формы совпадают, см. п.2(1).

**Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого**

*Большая часть отзывов были положительными*. **Допускается**. Надо: *Большая часть отзывов была положительной.*

Интересно то, что многие об этом правиле Розенталя вообще **не слышали.** Ссылок на правило при объяснении нет.

Comment: Sharon, посмотрите, пожалуйста, объяснение для "сыграно три новых роли". В пункте 3 говорится о несовпадении **ударения** форм. *Рóли* (Им.п мн.ч.) / *рóли* (Р.п. ед.ч.) – формы совпадают. А *ролей* – Р.п. **мн.** ч.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы исправила.  Проверьте еще раз, please.

Comment: "Алиса, ты меня не путай..." Суть не исправлена – **формы совпадают** (у вас "ролей" - это **мн.** ч., а надо "рóли". Получается так же, как с *медалями, партиями*. Тогда ссылаться надо на вот это: "На выбор формы определения может оказать влияние форма сказуемого; ср.: *Разыграны три золотые медали. – Разыграно три золотых медали*".

Comment: *Роли* – такие же *медали, партии и прочие чашки*. Можно: *"Сыгран**о** три нов**ых** роли"* и *"Сыгран**ы** три нов**ые** роли"*; *"Разбил**и**сь две красив**ые** чашки"*.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, постаралась учесть ваши замечания.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Хорошо было вспомнить эту путаную тему.

Answer (score 1):

До изменения вопроса там было написано, что нужно выбрать по интуиции или ‟чувству языка”. Хотелось бы уточнить, что это задание про грамматику – правила по которым слова сочетаются в предложения. Когда люди наблюдают использование языка, у них в голове формируются грамматические нормы, это не имеет ничего общего с интуицией, ‟чувством языка” и подобной метафизикой.

По поводу ответа. Все правильные, кроме ‟четыре остальных партии”. При сочетании с неодушевлёнными существительными, как ‟партии”, в винительном и именительном падеже будет ‟остальные”. Чтобы узнать правильный ответ на такое, нужно сперва посмотреть на падеж того слова, с которым согласуется слово ‟остальные”, это слово партии. У слова ‟партии” винительный или именительный падеж (зависит от положения в предложении), смотрим именительный и винительный падеж у слова ‟остальные”, – в обоих случая это ‟остальные”, поэтому ‟остальных” – это неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Это не правило Розенталя. ЛОЛ. Эта книга представляет из себя грамматический справочник. Розенталь не писал там какие-то свои правила, а описывал существующую грамматику.

В ответе обсуждается только ситуация два / три / четыре + определение + существительное в женском роде. В ответе не обсуждается ситуация со средним или мужским родом, так как тут никто никогда не допустит ошибку, никто не напишет: ‟Мы увидели два большие дома”. Непонятно, зачем вообще писать об этом в грамматическом справочнике, который должен содержать только те ситуации, которые вызывают колебания или споры.

В этом справочнике нет каких-то отчётливых рекомендаций. Там говорится, что **чаще** используется именительный падеж, но не говорится, насколько чаще: 20 на 80? 60 на 40? 51 на 49? Там нет никаких отчётливых инструкций. Если мы посмотрим на примеры, то они вполне себе звучат с родительным падежом (многие даже лучше звучат с родительным падежом):

Прекрасно звучит как: ‟В доме было две больших комнаты”, так и ‟В доме было две большие комнаты”;
прекрасно звучит как: ‟Я купила две фарфоровые чашки”, так и ‟Я купила две фарфоровых чашки”.

Это же касается подпункта про го́ры – горы́. Прекрасно звучит как: ‟Перед нами было две большие горы”, так и ‟Перед нами было две больших горы”;
прекрасно звучит как: ‟Две сильных руки подхватили ее”, так и ‟Две сильные руки подхватили ее”.
Если бы в такой ситуации была бы норма, что следует писать в родительном падеже, то для меня, как для носителя, это было бы очевидно, вариант с ‟две большие горы” вообще не звучал бы. И если бы такая норма была бы в языке, то мне не понадобилось метафизическое чувство языка, чтобы её приобрести и строить предложения по ней.

**В итоге:** помните, что зачастую если для вас, как для носителя, звучат оба варианта, то это значит, что оба варианта массово используются в такой синтаксической ситуации, а поэтому оба варианта допустимы. Помните, что мнение носителя важнее какого-то кривого описания грамматики в каком-то занюханном справочнике, где, вообще-то, нет никакой конкретики о том, как писать. В этой ситуации часто допустимы оба варианта. Какие-то исключения, где допустим только тот или иной вариант, наверное, есть, но они не описаны в справочнике – там дальше описываются ситуации, но в таких ситуациях ни у кого не возникнет колебаний или споров, как в сочетании ‟два бабушкиных сарафана”.

Никто не решает какие-то задачи в лингвистике. Не надо завидовать людям, которые занимаются нормальными науками. В чём заключается эта задача? В том, чтобы посмотреть в грамматический справочник?

Разблокируйте мой аккаунт, пожалуйста. Я обещаю соблюдать правила. Здесь полтора человека отвечают на вопросы, а вы забанили меня на год. Этот форум и так невероятно жалок.

Comment: "Две больш**и**е гор**ы**" паршиво звучит.

Comment: Нормально звучит.

Comment: Очень криво, не надо такое советовать.

Comment: Так напишите модераторам через чат, в котором сообщения о бане. (Меня тоже банили, поэтому знаю, как это.)

Comment: Там можно писать, если модератор добавляет эту возможность. Вроде бы у меня этой возможности нет.

Comment: Вроде бы она была (договаривались). Мне кажется, что модераторы не умышленно забанили на год. С каждой новой блокировкой время бана увеличивается в несколько раз. Потому что как бы рецидив. Думаю, время бана выставляется системой.